# Check for non matching rows in an outer join query with multiple keys

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables A and B, and a query like:

```
Select * from A left join B 
on A.key1=B.Key1
and A.key2=B.Key2
```

Can I identify non matching rows based on Key1 **OR** Key2 using only one join query?

I know I can use:

```
Select * from A left join B 
    on A.key1=B.Key1
    and A.key2=B.Key2
    where B.Key1 is null or B.Key2 is null
```

But it does only tell me that the couple Key1/Key2 from table A is not present in table B, but doesn't tell me which Key exactly is not present in Table B.

Thanks!

Comment: use right join in this case

Comment: I'm sorry but right join doesn't answer my question, how can a right join allow me to check if Key1 or Key2 from table A do not exist in table B?

Comment: @rocks Wrong. Very wrong.

Comment: Huh??? How is your second query supposed to work? `where B.Key1 is null` will prevent the join condition `A.Key1 = B.Key1` from EVER being true, so the whole thing will simply return all the rows of A regardless of how many matches there are; it will return even rows in A that do, in fact, have a match in B. Did you mean `select * from (select * from A left join B.....) where....`?

Comment: Besides, the whole question makes no sense. Suppose A has only one row, (1, 'a'). B has the rows (1, 'b') and (2, 'a'). The row in A has no match in B, but both keys are present in B. Sorry, but meaningless questions get a downvote from me.

Comment: ... and yet this question (which as I just explained is MEANINGLESS) has four answers already. Way to go SO! {:-)

Comment: you got it wrong @mathguy, try it on a fiddle :)

Comment: @HaytemBrB - yes, you are right about my first comment; `B.key1 is null` is applied only after the join condition (it is not pushed down to the base table, since the meaning would be different.) I stand by my second comment though - the question itself is meaningless.

Comment: @mathguy it is not, maybe you don't understand it, so I'll explain it to you in other words: I'm joining two tables A and B using two keys, how can I identify for each non matched row in A which key (key1 or key2) does not exist in B, using one query, and one join?

Comment: I gave you a simple example. Please answer your own question on that example.

Comment: Your example is interesting but not possible in my case, if table A has (1,'a') and table B have (1,'b'), then table B cannot have (2,'a'), and the answer of my question in this case is that Key2 does not exist in table B.

Comment: This is the first time you mention that. You should add it to your question, otherwise it remains meaningless.

Comment: @mathguy I asked a question, I got my answer, moving on then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need full outer join

```
Select * 
from A 
full outer join B on A.key1=B.Key1
                 and A.key2=B.Key2
where B.Key1 is null or B.Key2 is null 
   or A.Key1 is null or A.Key2 is null
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use "OR" ina  join:

```
Select * 
from A 
left join B 
on A.key1=B.Key1
or A.key2=B.Key2
```

Or is this the kind of logic you want?

```
select A.*,
       case
           when not exists (select 1 from B where B.key1 = A.key1) 
               and not exists (select 1 from B where B.key2 = A.key2)
               then 'None'
           when exists (select 1 from B where B.key1 = A.key1) 
               and exists (select 1 from B where B.key2 = A.key2)
               then 'Both'
           when not exists (select 1 from B where B.key1 = A.key1) 
               and exists (select 1 from B where B.key2 = A.key2)
               then 'Key2'
           when not (select 1 from B where B.key1 = A.key1) 
               and not exists (select 1 from B where B.key2 = A.key2)
               then 'Key1'
       end as Key_status
from A
```

Comment: You first query doesn't work properly, the result data set contains all records from `A` table.

Comment: Thank you but this query has 6 joins, I can do it using only 2 joins, but I need to do it in 1.

Comment: @JohnHC Second query also doesn't work. Are you sure that we can use `EXISTS` not only in `WHERE` clause?

Comment: @Surename Yes, Oracle allows case when exists

Answer (score 1):

If you want version with `UNION`

```
SELECT A.key1 AS key1, A.key2 AS key2 FROM A
UNION
SELECT B.key1 AS key1, B.key2 AS key2 FROM B
MINUS 
SELECT A.key1 AS key1, A.key2 AS key2 FROM A INNER JOIN B ON A.key1=B.Key1 AND A.key2=B.Key2
```

Answer (score 0):

You first have to create a primary_key(id in A) & foregin_key(id in B) in both tables, and then, you might can achieve it like this:

Here, i have dynamically created table according to your requirement, have a look:

```
DECLARE @table1 TABLE
( id INT, name NVARCHAR(20), key1 NVARCHAR(20), key2 NVARCHAR(20))
DECLARE @table2 TABLE
( id INT, key1 NVARCHAR(20), key2 NVARCHAR(20))

INSERT INTO @table1 VALUES
('1'     ,'name1',  'somekey1',    'secondo21'),
('2'     ,'name2',  'somekey10',   'seconn3'),
('3'     ,'name3',  'somekey3',    'city3'),
('4'    ,'name4',  'postal4',    'city4'),
('5'    ,'name5',  'postal55',    'city5'),
('6'    ,'name6',  'postal76',    'city56'),
('7'    ,'name7',  'postal77',    'city567')

INSERT INTO @table2 VALUES
('1',     'somekey1',    'secondo21'),
('8',    'postal2',    'seconn38'),
('3',      'somekey3',    'city3'),
('5',     'postal5',    'city5'),
('6'    ,'postal86',    'city96'),
('7'    ,'postal77',    'city577')

SELECT *,
CASE WHEN A.key1 = B.key1 AND A.key2 = B.key2 THEN 'All Matched' 
WHEN A.key1 = B.key1 AND A.key2 <> B.key2 THEN 'key2 Unmatched' 
WHEN A.key1 <> B.key1 AND A.key2 = B.key2 THEN 'key1 Unmatched' 
WHEN A.key1 <> B.key1 AND A.key2 <> B.key2 THEN 'key1 & key2 Both Unmatched' 
ELSE 'No row present in tblB with id '+ CONVERT(VARCHAR,A.id)
END  'unmatched'
 FROM @table1 A LEFT JOIN @table2 B ON A.id = B.id
```

Hope it helps. :)

Comment: To start with, this doesn't look like Oracle, which is clearly tagged and has not been altered since the initial posting, so this is a -1 right there. Moving on then.